# How can I optimize an algorithm to count combinations of a consecutive binary event? (In python or pseudocode)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, permutation, complexity-theory

Basically, the problem I am trying to solve is that I receive an input of an integer n to represent a sucession of elements. Each element can have a state 0 or 1. I need to count, in all possible arrangements of the sucession of elements, how many times there are three consecutive 1s.

To put a real life example:

> There are N chocolate bars in line at a store shelf. Each chocolate bar can either be dark chocolate or white chocolate. Of all the possible combinations, in how many there are 3 dark chocolate bars in a row?
> input: 4 > output: 3
> input: 5 > output: 8

Here is the code I already have in Python. It works perfectly with input 4 or 5, but around n > 20 (edit: more like n > 30) it starts crashing.

```
def count_combinations(n):    
count = 0
for i in range(2**n):
    binary = bin(i)[2:].zfill(n)  # Convert to binary and pad with zeros
    if '111' in binary:
        count += 1
return count
```

`

I figure that I'm missing some theory in order to tackle this problem, especially because I'm not being able to take the exponentiality of the code out. Any suggestion on what approach to take?

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to first count the combinations that do *not* have 3 consecutive 1s. So let's look at that problem first:

First the base cases:

- For  = 0, that (opposite) count is 1 (the empty sequence)
- For  = 1, it is 2 (a sequence of one 0 or one 1)
- For  = 2, it is 4 (sequences 00, 01, 10, and 11)

For a given  >= 3, we could look at the left most values and see what happens:

- If the left most value is 0, then the count is the same as for the remaining  - 1 elements.
- If the left most 2 values are 1 followed by 0, then the count is the same for the remaining  - 2 elements.
- If the left most 3 values are the sequence 1, 1 and 0, then the count is the same for the remaining  - 3 elements.

These are all the possible configurations we need to check, so the answer is the sum of the above.

This looks like a Fibonacci-like sequence, but with three instead of two terms. This is also called a [*tribonacci* sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Generalizations).

We can write the algorithm with a recursive function, but just like with the Fibonacci sequence, it is better to code this in an iterative, bottom-up way.

So we get this implementation:

```
def count_not_three(n):  # The opposite of what we need
    if n < 3:  # base cases
        return 1 << n  # Or: return (1, 2, 4)[n]
    # iterative, bottom-up, tribonacci:
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 4
    for i in range(n - 2):
        a, b, c = b, c, a+b+c
    return c
```

Now we need to get the count of sequences that *have* three consecutive 1s. For that we just need to count all combinations (without any condition) and subtract what we calculated above. So:

```
def count_three(n):
    # all binary combinations minus the ones that have no 3 consecutive 1s:
    return (1 << n) - count_not_three(n)
```

Here is how to get the output for a few values of :

```
for n in range(10):
    print(n, count_three(n))
```

The corresponding output:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 3
5 8
6 20
7 47
8 107
9 238
```

Comment: Amazing insight there in reducing the problem to calculating tribonacci numbers. Love it

Comment: Also worth noting-  the tribonacci numbers can be calculated in O(log n) time using either matrices + exponentiation by squaring, or a faster recurrence relation.

Comment: @DillonDavis "O(log n) time" - Not true. The result size (in bits) isn't even O(log n) but Theta(n). So you can't even *write* the result in O(log n) time, let alone *calculate* it in O(log n) time. Do you mean O(log n) additions/multiplications?

Comment: @KellyBundy Right, got a bit too hand-wavy there. The actual time (accounting for add/mul time) should be O(n log(n)), vs the O(n^2) of the answer, I think.

Comment: @DillonDavis I think that sounds right, at least in theory. Python `int`s don't use the asymptotically best multiplication algorithm, so I think it's still worse than that if you use those.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with a DFA counting the consecutive D(ark) chocolates:
[image: DFA]

```
def count_combinations(n):
    zero, one, two, three = 1, 0, 0, 0
    for _ in range(n):
        zero, one, two, three = zero+one+two, zero, one, two+2*three
    return three
```